# Different colors in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I try to add string with different colors in my UITextView. I wrote this code

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attString =
   [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:view.text]; //view is my UITextView
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName 
                  value:[UIColor greenColor] 
                  range:(NSRange){attString.length-8, 8}];
view.attributedText = attString;
```

Maybe it is incorrect attribute, can you tell me what attribute change color for text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` instead of `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`.

[*NSAttributedString attribute keys*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey?language=objc)