# Rainbow text in TextView, iOS and OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to add some different text colors to my app to be fused to an image. I've got alot of input that my users would like a rainbow text color and repeat. So for instance the word: `stackoverflow` would look like this: `s=red t=orange a=yellow c=green k=blue o=purple v=pink e=red r=orange f=yellow l=green o=blue w=purple`

I can't even begin to think how I can do this in one single `UITextView` 
Does anyone know how I could achieve this as the user is typing? Tips? Example?

I didn't see any other posts on SO regarding rainbow text for iOS. (correct me if im wrong)

Comment: Would this help? [Different colors in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823280/different-colors-in-uitextview)

Comment: You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` to achieve this

Comment: You mean like this app's 2nd screenshot ? https://itunes.apple.com/app/id671008306 
Check Introduction to Attributed Strings for iOS session from https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Comment: I changed the tag and question as, my answer covers iOS and OSX both, now this will target both the users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do using `NSAttributedString`:

*To make it a general method to support OSX and iOS. Now no need to change `NSColor` to `UIColor`, use this on both the operating systems.*

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    typedef UIColor Color;
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
    typedef NSColor Color;
#endif

-(NSAttributedString *)colorfulStringFrom:(NSString *)string{

    NSArray *colors = @[[Color redColor],
                        [Color yellowColor],
                        [Color greenColor],
                        [Color blueColor],
                        [Color purpleColor],
                        [Color magentaColor]
                        ];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:string];

    for (NSInteger location=0; location<string.length; location++) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(location, 1);
        Color *color = colors[location%colors.count];
        [attribString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];
    }
    return attribString;
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Wow, this was more than I asked for! Thanks so much!

Comment: @CokePokes: SO is not just for answering, its for learning. now only I learned how to make a method compatible with both OS. :)

Comment: Also, you can add any user-defined color instead of 15 pre-defined colors. Only few lines of code required to form new colors.

Comment: You can check for current character (string). If it is @"" then continue the loop and change the location counter.  Ana sorry now I am not having mac with me. Cant run and test. Will try 2mrw.