# Possible to have NSString with two font sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Is it possible to have one `NSString` that have the first word one font size / colour and the next word another font size and colour?

I was thinking maybe `NSAttributedString` - but not sure if thats the way to go?

I tried putting two `NSString` into `NSAttributedString` - but that didn't work.

Looking for a UILabel that has something like this:

> LARGEString(smallString)

**Working Example**

So far I have come up with this:

```
        /* Set the Font Sizes */

UIFont *objectNameFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
UIFont *itemsFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.f];

/* Create the attribute dictionaries */

NSDictionary *objectNameDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objectNameFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSDictionary *objectItemDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:itemsFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

/* Create the  string */

NSString *labelFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", object.name, object.items];

/* Seperate the two strings */

NSArray *components = [labelFullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" ("];
NSRange objectNameRange = [labelFullName rangeOfString:[components objectAtIndex:0]];
NSRange objectItemRange = [labelFullName rangeOfString:[components objectAtIndex:1]];

/* Create the Attributed string */
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelFullName];


/* Start the editiong */
[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.667 green:0.667 blue:0.667 alpha:1] /*#aaaaaa*/
                   range:objectItemRange];

[attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.271 green:0.271 blue:0.271 alpha:1] /*#454545*/
                   range:objectNameRange];

[attrString addAttributes:objectNameDict range:objectNameRange];

[attrString addAttributes:objectItemDict range:objectItemRange];

[attrString endEditing];
cell.title.attributedText = attrString;


return cell;
```

Which seems to work as I need it to. However, the separator for the two strings "(" is black and I need it to be same colour as `object.items` colour which is set here:

```
[attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.667 green:0.667 blue:0.667 alpha:1] /*#aaaaaa*/ range:objectItemRange];
```

**SOLUTION FOUND**

I found a solution that works for me:

I pulled the strings out and put them into an `NSArray` and used objectAtIndex to get their `NSRange` values to set the text
Any ideas?

Thanks all.

Comment: use Attributedstring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes you can have.**

Also you got the correct Class for that `NSAttributedString`.

*In the following code two font sizes 12 and 15 are used:*

```
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.f];
NSDictionary *attrsDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attribString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[words[0] substringFromIndex:1]  attributes:attrsDict];

UIFont *fontFirst=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.f];
NSDictionary *attrsDictFirst=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *firstString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[attribString subStringToIndex:1]  attributes:attrsDictFirst];

[attribString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)  withString:firstString];
```

For more, similar questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349076/rainbow-text-in-textview-ios-and-osx/22349918#22349918) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1395941%20nsattributedString).

Comment: Thank you. I am creating an NSString like this:
 NSString *categoryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)", object.text, object.text];

Could I use this one nsstring and still change the two words?

Comment: Can you see my updated questions? I'm almost there. Your answer he;pled a lot in getting me there. Thanks!